# Scene layer package (.slpk) and Portal for ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-portal, arcgis-enterprise, scene-layer-package

I have recently installed and federated an ArcGIS Server and a Portal (10.6.1). I am using the server as a hosting one as I have installed and configured the ArcGIS Datastore (Tile cache and Managed) altogether with a registered enterprise database. Everything seems to work nicely when publishing different map image/elevation/feature/tile cache layers. However, when I am trying to publish a .slpk, the process fails and I get the following error messages on both the server and the portal logs:

"*Failed to create couchdb database. Client tried to access password-protected page without proper authorization. (status code 401). Failed to execute (Publish Portal Service).*"

I have done different tests, publishing both from ArcGIS Pro and the Portal, with "Add item from my computer" and I get the same errors.

The solutions that I have already tried are the following:

[|FIXED| CityEngine SLPK and Portal for ArcGIS](https://community.esri.com/thread/210708-cityengine-slpk-and-portal-for-arcgis)

[Error: ERROR 001785: Unable to connect to the database used for scene caches (Unidentified Error)](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012513)

[Error: ERROR 001784: Unable to connect to the database used for scene caches (unauthorized)](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012516)

None of them worked in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I had been encountering a similar error: an Object Store Exception from portal and an 'Not authorized to access" error in the couch db log.  This occured at 10.7 and 10.7.1 whenever I tried to publish a scene layer from my scene package.

Because I think that when I originally set up the tile cache data store at 10.6 and registered it with my federated server, it registered as a stand-by data store.  Anyway, after trying many fixes including the ones you list above, I basically uninstalled, wiped all directories, and reinstalled the tile cache data store.

I configured the datastore directories on the data drive, making certain the domain account has full access, set the backup location and replaced the local cert with our CA cert.

I was then able to add an slpk and from their publish as a scene layer - all through the portal front end.  I have not been able to publish a scene layer from the api, still working on that piece

Comment: So for me, this turns out to be a bug in the tile cahce datastore logged by esri and is supposed to be fixed in the 10.8 release due in March 2020.  The bug is a size limit of >10mb, whether trying to publish the slpk fro the front end or through the api.